# BatchNormalization in tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to make custom model in tensorflow. I made functions to create basic layers, like Conv2D, Dense, Flatten. **I stuck with batch normalization implementation.**

I would like to have all `trainable_variables` (parameters) in one list `self.parameters`. Because my "custom" layers are built on [tf.Module](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules?hl=en#defining_models_and_layers_in_tensorflow) I assumed that all trainable variables will be avilable in `self.trainable_parameters`. Currently `self.trainable_variables` does **not** contain `MyBatchNormalization` trainable variables.

Below Colab example:

[Colab Example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ehEuArYi3__64l1Bct7JcOS3rWeJnTgF?usp=sharing) - Section "Create a model" prints layer name and trainable parameters.

I would like to have working BatchNormalization layer which trainable variables would be updated (trained) in `train_on_batch` method.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - I just added `__build(self, input_shape)` function, which calls `super(MyBatchNormalization, self).build(input_shape)` .

Implemetation below:

```
class MyBatchNormalization(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.out_shape = input_shape
        self.__build(input_shape)

    def __build(self, input_shape):
        super(MyBatchNormalization, self).build(input_shape)
```

I have not tested it completely yet. But I have access to `trainable_variables` of MyBatchNormalization and it looks promising.